# Why does rails think my object isn't persisted?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I have a situation where a `myobject.save!` is resulting in this error:

> PG::UniqueViolation: ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "things_pkey"
> DETAIL: Key (id)=(12345) already exists.
> : INSERT INTO "things" ("id", ...) VALUES (12345, ...) RETURNING "id"

So, rails has a persisted record but tries to do an insert instead of an update, and then includes the id in the insert (because, I'm guessing, in the insert case it's not accustomed to excluding any columns).

Further up in the code, there is a `save!` on the same object which may or may not have fired in the case I'm looking at. The only thing notable about this save is it happens inside a `rescue` block. I did some simple tests in console to see if for some reason an object isn't considered persisted if it's created inside a rescue block, and didn't find any such behavior.

What could be causing rails to think my object isn't persisted?

Comment: You will need to post more code to provide context. Right now we have no idea where you are calling `save!` at all (especially since you are calling it twice). Post the whole method where this is occurring and I am sure someone can provide a reasonable explanation

Comment: Alas, the code is very long so I wouldn't be able to make meaningful pseudocode easily. all the things it does are typical. assigning attributes and saving.

Comment: Unfortunately we won't be able to assist based solely on what is provided here, so I would recommend you at least try to summarize the issue in code by removing all the superfluous lines. Also as an aside the "code [being] very long" is sort of an issue in and of itself. Try and break it apart into smaller functional pieces which will make debugging much much easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out!

I was building the object with `user.things.build`. User#things was not an association. It's a method which returns an ActiveRecord::Relation. This method had recently changed, to be `Things.where(id: ...)`. So, rails was obediently using as much of the query as possible when building the new object.